# How does one show a Schauder basis is shrinking?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces, schauder-basis

I feel like I must be missing a trick - I'm self studying functional analysis and have come across Schauder bases, and I'm looking at different classifications e.g. shrinking, boundedly complete, unconditional bases.

A basis $\{e_i; e_i^*\}$ for a Banach space $X$ is *shrinking* if $\overline{\text{span}}\{e_i^*\} = X^*$, or in some books, if $\{e_i^*; e_i\}$ is a basis for $X^*$.

I understand this definition, and proofs of the first results about shrinking bases e.g. $\{e_i; e_i^*\}$ is shrinking if and only if
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lVert x_{\overline{\text{span}}\{e_i\}_{i \geq n}}^* \right\rVert = 0
$$
for every $x^* \in X^*$. But in all the books I've looked at, the author will follow up the definition saying it is immediate, obvious, clear that the standard basis for $c_0$ is shrinking, and for $\ell_p$ whenever $p>1$, but not for $\ell_1$. The last statement is clear to me, since $\ell_1^* \cong \ell_{\infty}$ is not separable so it can't have a basis, but I have no idea how one would show the others? Should I try and construct an isometric isomorphism between $\overline{\text{span}}\{e_i\}$ and $\ell_1$ for the case of $c_0$? I don't see how to do that without being able to describe a general element in $\overline{\text{span}}\{e_i\}$. Or should I use something like the equivalent condition I stated?

Comment: What do the biorthogonal functionals $(e_n^*)$ look like in this concrete cases? If you can figure this out the result is indeed immediate.

Comment: Okay, in this case $e_i^*$ maps a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to its $i^{th}$ entry. So for an arbitrary functional $x^*$ in the dual and sequence $x$ in the space, using linearity & continuity of $x^*$,
$$ x^*(x) = x^* \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e_n^*(x) e_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^*(e_n) e_n^*(x) $$
so that $x^* = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^*(e_n) e_n^* \in \overline{\text{span}}\{e_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. But wouldn't that work for $\ell_1$ too? So I must be mistaken.

Comment: Do you know the duality theorems for sequence spaces? I mean $(\ell_p)^* = \ell_q$ and $(c_0)^* = \ell_1$? If you do, try to think about what sequence corresponds to $e_i^*$.

Comment: About the case of $\ell_1$, you will not get $x^* = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^*(e_n) e_n^*$ in general (the sum converges pointwise but not in norm).

Answer (score 1):

A standard result is that a Banach space with a Schauder basis is reflexive iff the basis is shrinking and boundedly complete. The spaces $\ell_{p}$ for $1<p<\infty$ are reflexive so your result is immediate if you know this (James') theorem. For the $c_{0}$ case, note that $c_{0}^{*}\cong\ell_{1}$ and apply the definition of a shrinking basis.